# ov7670 camera module

Tags: arduino, sensor, camera, ram, fifo

I really need some help to figure out whether the ov7670 camera module I bought is with or without FIFO. I bought it from a local market.Can someone please tell me how can I find out whether the camera module I bought is with or without FIFO?? please..  :(

I also want to know what exactly is the role of FIFO here? (all I know is it serves as a buffer to store the image temporarily) and do we need to keep clearing the buffer each time or is it done automatically??

Please help..I am a newbie.

Here is how it looks...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has not consulted the data sheet (FIFO clearly shown) - question should be closed.

Comment: But where am I supposed to find the datasheet when I don't know which module's datasheet to look for(the one with FIFO or the one without FIFO)??
Sorry but i am really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs an external FIFO, as shown in Figure 2 on page 2 of [the datasheet](http://www.voti.nl/docs/OV7670.pdf).

**EDIT:** It doesn't necessarily need a FIFO - see [this post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=159557.msg1194455#msg1194455) for more info and code.

Comment: Thanks,I also want to know what exactly is the role of FIFO here? (all I know is it serves as a buffer to store the image temporarily) and do we need to keep clearing the buffer each time or is it done automatically??

Answer (score 2):

He most likely means the al422 FIFO. The al422 is an external chip that can hold an entire frame unlike the internal one. Either way the original poster was very lazy as there would be an IC chip that says al422. I have the same exact module that he does and I can confirm that it does not have an external FIFO chip.